# FormView loses data after onCommand event 2nd time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, formview

I'm trying to understand why does formview loses data if i click the button that populates it a 2nd time.

I have a repeater with an imagebutton with command that sets ID value to a hiddenfield and formview is automatically binded by the value on the hiddenfield.
So basically i click the button and hiddenfield gets value and formview is binded with data. What doesn't make sense, is if i click a 2nd time on the button the data disappears from formview?

this is where i bind formview

```
protected void rptADefinicaoExtrusao_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Completar" && e.CommandArgument.ToString() != "")
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);                 
            hdfRegistoID.Value = id.ToString();                    
        }
    }
}
```

the sqldatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="sdsADefinicao"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ValidacaoFormas_ConnectionString %>"
    UpdateCommand="sp_UPDATE_ADefinicao_Extrusao"
    UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    OnUpdated="sdsADefinicao_Updated"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    SelectCommand="sp_SELECT_ADefinicao">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdfRegistoID" Name="RegistoID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>

        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fvADefinicao" Name="ID_Registo" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Base_Cru" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Linha_Cru" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Diametro_Cru" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Espessura_Cru" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Comprimento_Cru" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Marcacao_Continua_Cru" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" Direction="Output" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and my formview basically to keep it short

```
<asp:FormView
    runat="server"
    ID="fvADefinicao"
    DataKeyNames="ID_Registo"
    DataSourceID="sdsADefinicao"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    HorizontalAlign="Center"
    OnItemUpdated="fvADefinicao_ItemUpdated"
    Style="width: 100%; max-width: 1200px;">

    <EditTemplate>

        Stuff...

    </EditTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

So i try to databind the formview directly from codebehind after hiddenfield gets the value and solves the problem. But is there another approach to this? I'm trying to reduce amount of code on codebehind.

UPDATE:

I found out what makes the formview losing data, if fieldset is disabled, after clicking button a 2nd time the data disappears. If I set the textbox to readonly it won't disappear

Comment: If you have your answer, please close this question, or post the answer below, and accept the answer.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question, I still have to write Databind on codebehind without knowing why does it lose data when clicking a 2nd time on the button

Comment: Ok. Let me see if I understand: you want to know if you really have to data-bind every time your page does a post-back to the server. It seems unnecessary or wasteful to databind each time.  Or are you losing some other values or settings?

Comment: the values disappear from the textboxes that are being binded with eval when i click the button a 2nd time

Comment: Could you also post the code for form_load().  Sometimes it contains code that does what you are describing.

Comment: i don't have any function called form_load(), if you mean page_load() i have no code in there